# could anyone guide me on this byref arguement type mismatch error?

Tags: c++, vb6

```
The code had been deleted due to the question was being solved. Really appreacite all the help
```

question is being solved so really appreciate all the help from the community.Love u all

Comment: You pass `sRespData` to `MTK_ConnectDevice()` but that's the Type name, you probably meant to pass the instance of that type: `sResp`.

Comment: @AlexK.Hi sir, i had re-edit the question and putting in the code which i use in header file and fixed the issue which u had mentioned, but after that, when i run the disconnect function, i would still facing the same error which is ** complile error:ByRef argument type mismatch** and i had no clue on how to fix it. but according to google, it means i do pass in the wrong parameter type, does it means i would need to change the datatype which declared in the type?Thank you.

Comment: Did you change `MTK_ConnectDevice(Port, BaudRate, sRespData)` to `MTK_ConnectDevice(Port, BaudRate, sResp)` ?

Comment: I don't "speak" C++ at all, but if I read that correctly `char strMsg[512]` is a character (array) of size 512, whereas `Message As String` in VB is a (dynamic length) BSTR. Typically in VB a `Byte()` array is used when passing data to a C++ method expecting `char[]`. Or use a BSTR in the C++ structure instead.

Comment: @AlexK. . yes, i do have change to `MTK_ConnectDevice(Port, BaudRate, sResp)` but whenever i click run on it, it would mention the same error as this `ByRef argument type mismatch`

Comment: @HelO'Ween sorry, i got abit confuse with this. is that mean for the c++ code `char strMsg[512]` , i would need to change the `char` to `BSTR` as well ? i go will give it a try and come back if the issue still continue haha, it was making me so frustrated since suppose it is just 2 simple function which used to make me familiar with project and i was not able to finish it for such a long time haiz... suddenly got that feel should i give up on this job lol haha

Comment: hi, thank you for helping me on solving this issue and the issue was solve... the real problem was occur on `Dim sResp As sRespData` dim default was making my declare as private so whenever the compiler was not able to find it due it was private, thats why the error `Byref arguement type mismatch` was occur and after changing `dim to public` the issue was solved and no more`Byred arguement type mismatch`, no matter how , i really really appreciate both of u who willing to wasting time to answer my question and trying to help me solve it. i really really appreciate and thank you once again

Comment: Glad you solved it.  If you make the very first line of code in any VB6 file `Option Explicit` then you will get an error when this happens again (i.e. when you try to use a variable that is not declared)

Comment: @AlexK. yup. will put `Option Explicit` on all the vb6 file starting from now haha, due without it when i compile it was like no error at all until when running it, but after adding `Option Explicit` it immediately show error out when i compile the code, its quite useful for the newbie coder like me haha.And really appreciate for all ur help. Thank you