# Could anyone teach me on how to unpack the return value?

Tags: c++

below is the code which had writted in c++ and basically what this function do would be pack the value into hex and unpack the return value in hex

```
  abc_API_API long __stdcall ABC_ExecuteCommand(slngCommandParameter *lngCmdPrmCode, shexRespData *hexRespData, sRespData *Data)
    {
        long lngResult, lngRtn;
        char strMsg[512];
        memset((void*)strMsg, '\0', sizeof(strMsg));
        shexCommandParameter hexCmdPrmCode;
    
        try {
    
            sCmdData cmdData;
            PBYTE pbRDTBuff;
            PDWORD pcbRDTLength;
            PCRSTATUS lpStatus;
    
             MappingTable(&hexCmdPrmCode, lngCmdPrmCode);
            sprintf_s(strMsg, "Command  : [%X]%s", hexCmdPrmCode.HexCommandCode, hexCmdPrmCode.Command.c_str());
             WriteLog(strMsg);
            sprintf_s(strMsg, "Parameter: [%X]%s", hexCmdPrmCode.HexParameterCode, hexCmdPrmCode.Parameter.c_str());
             WriteLog(strMsg);
    
            cmdData.bCMDByte1 = 'C';
            cmdData.bCMDByte2 = 'D';
    
            char *lpCMPBuff = new char[lngCmdPrmCode->lngDataSize + 1];
            lpCMPBuff[(lngCmdPrmCode->lngDataSize)] = '\0';
            cmdData.cbCMPLength = USHORT(lngCmdPrmCode->lngDataSize);
    
            if (lngCmdPrmCode->lngDataSize > 0) 
                 PackBCDHex(lpCMPBuff, strRemoveSpace(lngCmdPrmCode->strData), (lngCmdPrmCode->lngDataSize) * 2);
    
            cmdData.pbCMPBuff = LPBYTE(lpCMPBuff);
    
    
            lngResult = F3_ExecCommand (g_Reader, cmdData.bCMDByte1, cmdData.bCMDByte2 , cmdData.pbCMPBuff, cmdData.cbCMPLength, pbRDTBuff, pcbRDTLength, lpStatus);
            if(lngResult == F3_S_SUCCESS) {
    
                lngRtn = 0;
                
            } else {
                lngRtn = -1;
                
            }
    
            Data->ErrCode = (long)lngResult;
            Data->Message = SysAllocStringByteLen(strMsg, strlen(strMsg));
             WriteLog(strMsg);
            return lngRtn;
    
        } catch (exception& e) {
            sprintf_s(strMsg, "Exception@ABC_DeniedInsertion: %s", e.what());
             WriteError(strMsg);
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

but i had no clue on how to properly unpack the data which suppose to put in this line

```
if(lngResult == F3_S_SUCCESS) {

   lngRtn = 0;

  } else {
   lngRtn = -1;

  }
```

below would the the unpack function which would be used

```
 UnpackBCDHex
```

what i know is when lngResult is equal to 0 which means success, then the pbRDTBuff would point to the buff of the response data,and when pcbRDTLength >0 then i would need to assign an array and put the data in and using  UnpackBCDHex to unpack it. but i have no clue on how can i achieve it. can anyone can guide me or showing me which document i can refer to finish this function?

thank you

**HI, The problem had been solved. Thank you for all the help.Really really appreciate for those who willing spend their time and inbox chating with me teaching me step by step and trying to help me figure out the issue together.I really love this community which is such beginner friendly.Love u all 3000 haha**

Comment: This looks very similar to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65771596/7582247) and connected to [Initialize function for the Device by using enum](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?890205-Initialize-function-for-the-Device-by-using-enum) - I found no other uses of `modcommon_library <function>` on the net. What is that `modcommon_library` that you put infront of the functions?

Comment: ... and where do I find the documentation for `PackBCDHex`?

Comment: yes, they look very similiar to my other question and connected to Initialize Function for the Device by using enum due they actually all connected, due 1st question was like asking where is the part i done is wrong , and this question would link with i able to Initialize Function for the Device by using enum. The reason i click that question as solved due i realize that if i want to use enum , i would require to change the method i use on the execute command which is this question.

Comment: for that `modcommon_library` its actually is a name for my header file. since i not doing everything in one page, so i do have open another header file which named as `modcommon_library`and the function behind it is actually im calling the function from the header file

Comment: So, your code doesn't really contain a line like `modcommon_library PackBCDHex ...`? Please turn this into a [mre] where we can see the the functions you've defined. It's kind of hard to get the full picture without knowing what's happening in those.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi, thank you for replying me in such a short time, i had re-edit the post and post the pack and unpack function out so it might be easier for u to see what function i have defined. Due current issue is due to the pack function is for the value which i input so i understand how to dump it in, but for the unpack function, it was actually need to use the return value of the device, so i got abit confuse on how should i link the return value from device together with the unpack function. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227636/discussion-between-kobayashi-and-ted-lyngmo).